# How to make element scrollable according to scrollbox content using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My requirement is to scroll the slider control according to the scroll box content box using JQuery. 
and accordingly change the content on the left hand side. How can I achieve this using Jquery, I tried making the control scroll able using scroll but it is not scrolling.

Following is my example https://codepen.io/divya95/pen/GRogLoR

Following is my code:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="flex-scroll tab__margin">
        <div class="describe">
          <p>Cognitive workflow deliver omi-channel business's journey</p>

        </div>
        <div class="slider-column">
          <div class="avatar-column">
            <div class="avatar"></div>

          </div>
          <div class="solutions">
            <div>
              <h5>Email, Chat & Voice</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5>Web & Mobile</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5>Whatsapp, Facebook, Twitter</h5>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.flex-scroll {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider-column {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column;   */
}
.describe {
    width: 95%;
}
.solutions {
    border-left: 3px solid #2492f8;
    height:150px; 
    overflow:auto;
}
.avatar-column {
    padding-right: 32px;


}
.avatar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.avatar::after {
    content: "";
    width: 22px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #9dcffb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -31px;
    outline: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: you mean when someone clicks on the item in the list in right section, the 'avatar' container should slide to that item in the list and the corresponding content in the left section should update.

Comment: No, When someone scrolls down  avatar circle element  the corresponding content should change on the left section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, check this solution using jQuery. You can tweak it as per your need.

- On mousedown on avatar div and mousemove different section content are shown based on scroll position.
- On mouseup the slider points to first child and show the content for it.
- Please note: there is an assumption here that the height of all the child elements are same, else it will affect accuracy of when content switching happens on left side. It is enforced by setting a height value for `.child` class in `css`.

Test the solution in 'Full Page' mode.

```js
(function($) {
  const $slider = $("#circleslider");
  const $products = $("#products");
  const $contentDiv = $("#div1");
  const $avatarColumn = $('.avatar-column');
  const $children = $products.find('.child');

  // assuming height of all child same.
  // grab the child element height for one for calculation 
  // purposes.
  const childHeight = Math.ceil($children.first().outerHeight(true));
  const avatarColumnHeight = $avatarColumn.height();
  const productsColumnHeight = childHeight * $children.length;
  const sliderInitialPosition = $slider.position();
  const sliderOffset = $slider.offset();
  const avatarColumnOffset = $avatarColumn.offset();
  
  let isClicked = false;
  let initialMouseOffset;
  const sliderRangeMin = $slider.height()/2;
  const sliderRangeMax = $avatarColumn.height() - $slider.height();
  const effectiveSliderHeight = sliderRangeMax - sliderRangeMin;
  const childHeightEquivalentInSlider = effectiveSliderHeight/$children.length;

  // text corresponding to each product choice
  const texts = [
    "section 1",
    "section 2",
    "section 3",
    "section 4",
    "section 5",
    "section 6",
    "section 7",
    "section 8",
    "section 9",
    "section 10",
    "section 11",
    "section 12",
    "section 13",
    "section 14",
    "section 15"
  ];

  if ($slider.length) {
    $slider.on("mousedown", (e) => {
      isClicked = true;
      initialMouseOffset = e.pageY - avatarColumnOffset.top;
      $contentDiv.css('user-select', 'none');
    });

   
    $(document).on("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (isClicked === true) {
        // change position of the slider
        const minMouseListen = sliderRangeMin > initialMouseOffset ? initialMouseOffset : sliderRangeMin;
        const maxMouseListen = sliderRangeMax + (initialMouseOffset - sliderRangeMin);
        const maxSliderTop = $avatarColumn.height() - $slider.height();
        const mouseOffset = e.pageY - avatarColumnOffset.top;
        if (mouseOffset > minMouseListen && mouseOffset < maxMouseListen) {
          $slider.css('top', ((mouseOffset - minMouseListen) > maxSliderTop ? maxSliderTop : (mouseOffset - minMouseListen)) + 'px');
        } else if (mouseOffset <= minMouseListen) {
          $slider.css('top', sliderInitialPosition.top + 'px');
        } else {
          $slider.css('top', maxSliderTop +'px');
        }
        
        // scroll the content section on the right
        const sliderStep = (mouseOffset - minMouseListen) / childHeightEquivalentInSlider;
        const scrollMultiplier = productsColumnHeight/effectiveSliderHeight;
        const sliderCurrentTop = $slider.position().top;
        const scrollPosition = sliderCurrentTop * scrollMultiplier;
        $products.scrollTop(scrollPosition);
        
        // change content in left section
        let textIndexToShow = Math.floor(sliderStep);
        $contentDiv.text(texts[textIndexToShow] || texts[texts.length]);
      }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseup", (e) => {
      resetSlider();
    });
    
    function resetSlider() {
    if (isClicked === true) {
        isClicked = false;
        scrollSlowDownRate = 0;
        scrollSpeedUpRate = 0;

        // reset content section on right
        $products.scrollTop(0);
        $contentDiv.text(texts[0]);
        $contentDiv.css('user-select', 'auto');

        // reset slider
        $slider.css('top', sliderInitialPosition.top + 'px');
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  width: 70%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.slider-column {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column;   */
}

.describe {
  width: 50%;
}

.icons {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

i {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.solutions {
  border-left: 3px solid #2492f8;
  max-height: 300px;
  /*   overflow-y: scroll; */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}

.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  user-select: none;
}

.avatar-column {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 32px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: grey;
}

.avatar::after {
  content: "";
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #9dcffb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: -31px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="flex-scroll tab__margin slider__padding">
    <div class="describe">
      <div id="div1">section 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-column">
      <div class="avatar-column">
        <div class="avatar" id="circleslider"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="solutions" id="products">
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 1</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 2</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 3</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 4</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 5</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 6</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 7</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 8</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 9</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 10</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 11</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 12</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 13</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 14</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <h5>Section 15</h5>
          <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-map" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solutions works, but I want to move the avatar also along with sliding so I tried setting translateY according to scroll Position but it is going to the last end so how can I do this ?

Comment: sure, I have updated the answer to make the slider move, however as sections on right move in opposite direction to the slider, the scroll multiplier needs to be adjusted to properly match the slider pointer to the section. I haven't refined that.